# Make changes in string at the run time

Tags: java, string

I want to make some change in string at the run time. In the code bellow I'm trying to change int variable `count` so that string s would also change.

The result I thought would be like this:

```
You have invited 0 users.
You have invited 5 users.
```

But in both case there were 0:

```
You have invited 0 users.
You have invited 0 users.
```

Can you please explain me why my idea did not work and what should I do make it work?

```
static int count;

static String s = "You have invited " + count + " users.";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(s);

    count = 5;

    System.out.println(s);

}
```

Comment: Right now I'm too lazy to explain things, so I'll let someone else get the reputation points for that. Here's a cheap solution: https://hastebin.com/iguwequziw.cs

Comment: @kavita You should post an answer

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an accessor-method, like a `getter` and make your `count` an instance variable:

```
private int count = 0;

private String getString(){
    return "You have invited " + this.count + " users.";
}
```

which then can be called like this:

```
System.out.println(getString()); // prints: You have invited 0 users.
this.count = 5;
System.out.println(getString()); // prints: You have invited 5 users.
```

This is because like already said in *@YCF_L*s answer `Strings` are immutable. What that means is that once the string is created. It can't be changed. The only way is to overwrite it with a new String (which still not changes the value, but only changes the reference of the variable `s` to the new string)

Comment: `count` doesn't have to be instance variable. `getString` could take `count` as parameter.

Comment: Good solution, although it does not answer "Can you please explain me why my idea did not work..."

Comment: Ah, much better ;)

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia of course. My answer is only one approach which can be used to go around OPs problem. Your way works as well.

Answer (score 4):

String are immutable, so when you use `count = 5;` in fact you are not changing `s`. To make the changes you have to use :

```
count = 5;
s = "You have invited " + count + " users.";
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: @kavita *Everytime, you make any change in already existing string*. You **can't** change strings. You can only change the reference of a variable to a new string

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable. Everytime, you make any change in already existing string, you need to re-assign that, to reflect the changes. In your case, you have changed count variable. But, after changing it, you need to re-assign the string to variable `s`. Or, in simple words, you need to create new string with `count` variable and assign it to some variable i.e. in your case, it is `s`

Answer (score 3):

As other people stated, your modification of `count` won't alter the value of `s`.

What you could do is to use [String.format(String ,
                            Object...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) :

```
static final String s = "You have invited %d users.";

// then later...

System.out.println(String.format(s, count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the ***count*** has changed, the ***s*** has not changed and has always been "You have invited 0 users. "

1.int ***count*** is a Basic Data Types Variables.

2.Even if ***count*** is a reference type, String is Immutable, unless re-assignment.

```
static int count;

static String s = "You have invited " + count + " users.";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(s);
    count = 5;
    s = "You have invited " + count + " users.";

    System.out.println(s);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
static int count;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCount();        
    count = 5;
    printCount();
}

public static void printCount() {
    System.out.println("You have invited " + count + " users.");
}
```

Comment: whether the field is static or not does not affect the problem that the OP was having

Comment: count defined as static, should not be instance variable to solve the problem right?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.